# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't find implementation for Permissions interface

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, expo, expo-notifications

My expo react-native application is working perfectly fine locally, in dev mode (Expo Go). But it crashes mercilessly in production when downloaded from Google Play Store and upon installation. Using logcat, the error message is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't find implementation for Permissions interface.
```

The only permission related code is a notifications permission request with `expo-notifications`.

```
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
...
await ExpoNotifications.getPermissionsAsync();
...
await ExpoNotifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you for helping solve this issue.

Comment: I had the same issue.. I solved it by removing expo-permission.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered a similar issue.

Seems that `expo-permissions` is **deprecated**. Reference [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions/).

What solved my issue was to remove expo-permission package from the project.

```
cd ProjectName

expo uninstall expo-permissions
```

**OR**

```
npm uninstall expo-permissions
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and managed to get it work after updating expo-notifications:

```
npm install expo-notifications@0.12.2
```

Other people mentioned that they had to update other expo related packages because expo-permissions is deprecated, just like @sanjeev mentioned above.